# theme in asp page

Tags: asp.net, themes

i am having a html form in which i had given a theme. now i want to show that theme in div tag in asp page..
my html page is :

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body background="file:/C:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/themes/images8.jpg">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>
   header_picture
    </h1>
    <img src="file:/C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Water lilies.jpg"  style="width:480px; height:150px; background-position:centre;"/>

    </div>
    <div>
    <h1>
    here comes the content
    </h1>
    </div>
    <div>
    <h2>
    footer_picture
    </h2>
    <img src="file:/C:/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/My Pictures/Sample Pictures/Blue hills.jpg" style="width:480px; height:150px; background-position:centre;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and i use the code to display the theme as :

```
<asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" Width="80px" Height="80px" ImageUrl="~/themes/form.html"/>
```

but this is not showing any theme.
please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an html page to `ImageUrl` attribute so it won't work.

Please map it to the required `Image` file if you want that image to be displayed in the webpage.